# How to group by month and year?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, group-by

I have a table PURCHASE with a date column PURCHASEDATE which is in DATE format. I'm trying to get the purchases grouped by month and year. To do so, I try with:

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(PURCHASEDATE, 'MM YYYY') AS MONTHYEAR 
FROM PURCHASE
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(PURCHASEDATE, 'MM YYYY');
```

I have also tryied with `GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PURCHASEDATE), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PURCHASEDATE)` but neither worked.

I'm rusty with SQL querys :S.

**EDIT**

Table cloumns

[image]

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Edited with columns from purchase table, is that what you're asking?

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: I want to display purchases grouped by month and year. If there are two on november 2020, i just need 1 row

Comment: No problem exists with your [cases](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=76476b687fe74e200bf1f559c429257a) , you can add some aggregatio such as `SUM(total) AS total, COUNT(code) AS count` to the SELECT list also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE purchase ( purchasedate ) AS
SELECT DATE '2019-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-02-01' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-01' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-03-01' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-04-01' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1;
```

Then, you can use your query:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(PURCHASEDATE, 'MM YYYY') AS monthyear,
       COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM   PURCHASE
GROUP BY
       TO_CHAR(PURCHASEDATE, 'MM YYYY');
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> MONTHYEAR | FREQUENCY
> :-------- | --------:
> 03 2020   |         4
> 01 2019   |         5
> 01 2020   |         3
> 02 2020   |         2
> 02 2019   |         3
> 04 2020   |         1
> ```

Or, you can use `TRUNC`:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(PURCHASEDATE,'MM') AS monthyear,
       COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM   PURCHASE
GROUP BY
       TRUNC(PURCHASEDATE,'MM');
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> MONTHYEAR           | FREQUENCY
> :------------------ | --------:
> 2020-03-01 00:00:00 |         4
> 2020-04-01 00:00:00 |         1
> 2020-02-01 00:00:00 |         2
> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |         3
> 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |         5
> 2019-02-01 00:00:00 |         3
> ```

Or, you can use `EXTRACT`:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM PURCHASEDATE) AS year,
       EXTRACT( MONTH FROM PURCHASEDATE) AS month,
       COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM   PURCHASE
GROUP BY
       EXTRACT( YEAR FROM PURCHASEDATE),
       EXTRACT( MONTH FROM PURCHASEDATE);
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> YEAR | MONTH | FREQUENCY
> ---: | ----: | --------:
> 2019 |     1 |         5
> 2020 |     1 |         3
> 2020 |     2 |         2
> 2020 |     4 |         1
> 2019 |     2 |         3
> 2020 |     3 |         4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c5ec7573cfe86407e572b1f1f18a110a)*

Comment: The point was i was using MONTHYEAR alias, and order by PURCHASEDATE... Thanks for detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```sql
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(PURCHASEDATE, 'MM YYYY') AS MONTHYEAR,
    SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL
FROM PURCHASE
GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR(PURCHASEDATE, 'MM YYYY');
```

Comment: I see now, the problem is that some aggregation funcion is mandatory. Thanks!

Comment: @JuanPizaFerra It is not mandatory, you can have `GROUP BY` without any aggregation functions [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=18301e25bde0162f0634a3e457ab3868) (however, you need to include all the non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`).